# react native displaying items within 2KM

Tags: react-native

I have a large database of items and they each have a location field which stores their longitude and latitude . I only want to display the items within 2KM to the users location .
Since my database is huge , creating an array by mapping through each database item and use getDistance from geolib is not very efficient . Is there any other way i can do this effectively .

Thanks any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you give additional details on your database? Does it support geospatial queries? Which?

Comment: @tucuxi dynamodb database . for each item , theres a location field e.g "4.75670.6654" which has the lat/long appended.